# How to render polyline points which is present only within visual bounds

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms, uwp, maps, polyline

I am adding a polyline to the imagery layer, in that I need to render only the polyline points which is present inside the visual bounds in zooming and panning. Is there any generic solution to achieve this?

[image]

From the above image, red line denotes the polyline and green line denotes visual bounds.

Comment: Could you explain render only the polyline points which is present inside the visual bounds. Does it mean you want to render cross-over point ?

Comment: I want draw only the polyline which is present inside the visual bounds.

Comment: Ok, I think you could make new white rectangle that padding same as visual bounds  cover on the visual bounds to hide extra polyline.

Comment: No, I don't want to hide the extra polyline. I only need to draw the polyline inside visual bounds.

Comment: If you do want to dray the inside polyline directly, you need re-calculate path data  and render again.

Comment: Yes, I am currently asking about that logic only @CoCaIceDew

Comment: it's hard for me, I' not familiar with the path logic. for design point, we suggest you use mask to cover the extra polyline

Comment: We can hide extra polyline using mask, But, I want to draw the polyline inside the visual bounds to improve the performance. If, I use mask it will not improve the performance.